# Too many solutions from equations, how to select the best answer

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following set of equations to get a1, a2, a3.
The code shown below produces too many solutions, my solution lies in it...how do i select it...
in the attached picture, i am showing the code and the long list of solutions...i have highlighted the solution that i require in the blue colored box....how to i get this result only???

```
ClearAll;
Vdc1 = 1;
v1 = 0.15;
eqn = {(4 Vdc1)/π (Cos[a1 Degree] - Cos[a2 Degree] + Cos[a3 Degree]) - v1 == 0,
       (4 Vdc1)/(3π) (Cos[3 a1 Degree] - Cos[3 a2 Degree] + Cos[3 a3 Degree]) == 0,
       (4 Vdc1)/(5π) (Cos[5 a1 Degree] - Cos[5 a2 Degree] + Cos[5 a3 Degree]) == 0
      };
Solve[eqn, {a1, a2, a3}]  (* find so that 0<a1<a2<a3<π/2 *)
```

[image]

Need to extract the highlighted.

Comment: Why dont you give those restrictions to the `Solve` command???

Comment: `Select[sols, Quiet[ineq /. #] &]`, with or without `Quiet`?  (Inequalities complain about complex numbers.

Comment: Since {a1, a2, a3}` are degrees, the constraint should presumably be `0 < a1 < a2 < a3 < 90`

Comment: how do u give restrictions to the solve command ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Vdc1 = 1;
v1 = 15/100;
```

I had no luck adding constraints to `Solve`

```
Solve[{
  (4 Vdc1)/(\[Pi]) (Cos[a1 Degree] - Cos[a2 Degree] + 
       Cos[a3 Degree]) - v1 == 0,
  (4 Vdc1)/(3 \[Pi]) (Cos[3 a1 Degree] - Cos[3 a2 Degree] + 
      Cos[3 a3 Degree]) == 
   0, (4 Vdc1)/(5 \[Pi]) (Cos[5 a1 Degree] - Cos[5 a2 Degree] + 
      Cos[5 a3 Degree]) == 0,
  0 < a1,
  a1 < a2,
  a2 < a3,
  a3 < 90
  },
 {a1, a2, a3}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can use the same format for `Reduce`. It appeared to take a long time and I did not wait for it to finish to see if it produced an answer.

Instead I tried `FindMinimum`. It expects a function so I summed up the square of the inputs which is more or less equivalent to equating them to zero.

```
FindMinimum[
 {
  ((4 Vdc1)/\[Pi] (Cos[a1 Degree] - Cos[a2 Degree] + Cos[a3 Degree]) -
       v1 )^2 +
   (4 Vdc1)/(3 \[Pi]) (Cos[3 a1 Degree] - Cos[3 a2 Degree] + 
       Cos[3 a3 Degree])^2 +
   (4 Vdc1)/(5 \[Pi]) (Cos[5 a1 Degree] - Cos[5 a2 Degree] + 
       Cos[5 a3 Degree])^2,
  0 < a1 && a1 < a2 && a2 < a3 && a3 < 90
  },
 {
  a1,
  a2,
  a3
  }
 ]
```

The answer was produced quickly

```
{3.65723*10^-12, {a1 -> 42.5831, a2 -> 47.3491, a3 -> 86.6151}}
```

Comment: This is the answer is am getting                                                   
         {0.680728, {a1 -> 0.692134, a2 -> 13.5875, a3 -> 49.8621}}

Comment: In your original question you had some typos (i.e., using square brackets rather than curly brackets, etc...). I tried to correct those in the answer. If I start with a fresh Mathematica session and paste in the the top two lines and the `FindMinimum` line I duplicate the result in the answer. I am using Mathematica 11.1.1.0

Comment: Although taking about five minutes, `Reduce` does offer the advantage of finding all answers satisfying the equations.  In this case there is only one, `{a1 -> 42.5833, a2 -> 47.3492, a3 -> 86.6151}`

Answer (score 0):

As I have kept mentioning many times before, such problems are best handled through the Weierstrass substitution. The substitution is especially convenient here, since the angle restrictions are also very easily imposed:

```
With[{Vdc1 = 1, v1 = 15/100}, 
     NSolve[Join[TrigExpand[{(4 Vdc1)/(π) (Cos[a1] - Cos[a2] + Cos[a3]) - v1 == 0,
                             (4 Vdc1)/(3 π) (Cos[3 a1] - Cos[3 a2] + Cos[3 a3]) == 0,
                             (4 Vdc1)/(5 π) (Cos[5 a1] - Cos[5 a2] + Cos[5 a3]) == 0} /.
                            Thread[{a1, a2, a3} -> 2 ArcTan[{u1, u2, u3}]]],
                 {0 < u1 < 1, 0 < u2 < 1, 0 < u3 < 1}], {u1, u2, u3}]]
   {{u1 -> 0.942601, u2 -> 0.43844, u3 -> 0.389715},
    {u1 -> 0.389715, u2 -> 0.43844, u3 -> 0.942601}}

2 ArcTan[{u1, u2, u3}]/° /. %
   {{86.6151, 47.3492, 42.5833}, {42.5833, 47.3492, 86.6151}}
```